# Count down timer trouble android

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a question. I have a timer that looks like a progress bar moving backwards. Now it works good or I should say well on older phones but the newer one with the HD screens well it doesn't work well. The timer bar is set vert and match_parent in my xml.
I am including my method below can you look at it and tell me how i can improve it?

```
//used to animate timer bar
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

//timer event code
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           final long start = startTime; 
// startTime will come from a spinner it will be 0,1,2,3,4 or 5 (users choice) 
// ** the bar is GREEN until the if condition is meet
           long currentLength = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
           long remainingTime = gameTime - currentLength;
           float x = (float)remainingTime / (float)gameTime;

           if(remainingTime > 0)
           {
               //still have time remaining - update UI
               LinearLayout timerUI = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timerUI);
               timerUI.getLayoutParams().height =  (int) (x * 400);

               //update color
               if(remainingTime < 15000)
                  timerUI.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
               else if(remainingTime < 30000)
                   timerUI.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

               timerUI.requestLayout();
               timerUI.invalidate();
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
           }
           else
           {
               if(monitorThread != null)
                   monitorThread.interrupt();

                //NEED to push user to final screen
                Intent resultsIntent = new Intent(SingleGameActivity.this, 
                    ResultsActivity.class);
                startActivity(resultsIntent);
           }
       }
    };
```

Comment: Doesn't work well means? A little more information about your problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok when run on the HTC (2.3.3) it works like it should. When run on the Nexus 4.1 the bar does not go away like it should. it breaks up and leaves some of the colored bar in place.